# How do i reassemble a Arrow Powershop Pro 8000 staple gun?

Tags: tools, jamb, project-planning

I have a Powershop Pro 8000 staple gun that jammed on me. So I opened it up to fix jam and it came all apart. How do I reassemble it? Is there a site I can get a diagram of the inside of it?

Comment: Start out by including a few pictures of it so we can see what you're dealing with.

Comment: Does [SOLVED: ASSEMBLY I have a B&D Powershot staple gun..I need - Fixya](https://www.fixya.com/support/t185610-assembly) help?